# XML Parsing - CDATA

Tags: xml, parsing, cdata

I'm just wondering when using CDATA in XML if i get the text content of an XML element will the text include the CDATA tags?

For instance:

Say I have xml like:

```
<name>
   <![CDATA[ 
      my <text> here 
   ]]>
</name>
```

If I got the text content of the "name" element would the output be:

```
<![CDATA[ my <text> here ]]>
```

or would it simply be:

```
my <text> here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm just wondering when using CDATA in XML if i get the text content of an XML element will the text include the CDATA tags?

No (assuming the library you are using isn't broken). The CDATA markers are not content.